# Scoring System In Cocos2D

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, scoring

My game has a collision detection where when my missile hits the enemy the enemy disappears. I want to add a scoring system that adds 1 point every time my missile hits the enemy. I'll post my game code below (I used the HelloWorldLayer.m)**

Here is the code:

Link - http://pastebin.com/iGP83SCv

In the collision section i just want it to add 1 point every time the projectile hits the enemy "sprout" and display the score in label. Example: Score:0000

PS, please explain it as easy as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@synthesize` a "score" property of type `int`, and a "scoreLabel" property of type `CCLabelTTF`.

initialize your score property to "0" in `-(void)init`

On line 126, increment your "score" property by 1, and set that value into your `CCLabelTTF`.