# Cocos2D scoring game

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, sdk, cocos2d-iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Scoring System In Cocos2D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11970067/scoring-system-in-cocos2d)

**I got a reply from a question I asked earlier but I am new to coding and have no idea how to do it. Here is the reply:**

> **"**@synthesize a "score" property of type int, and a "scoreLabel" property of type CCLabelTTF.
>
> initialize your score property to "0" in -(void)init
>
> On line 126, increment your "score" property by 1, and set that value into your CCLabelTTF.**"**

Can you tell me how to do this? plz. link to my other post

----- [Scoring System In Cocos2D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11970067/scoring-system-in-cocos2d)

Comment: You should not post a new question like this, continue the conversation on your first question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you synthesize a private variable (other classes cannot see it) you allow a way for other classes to see and/or modify the value of that variable.

First, you want to create the variable:

```
NSMutableArray *_targets;
NSMutableArray *_projectiles;

int _score;
CCLabelTTF *_scoreLabel;
```

Then in your init method to set the `_score` to `0`:

```
-(id) init
{
    if( (self=[super init] )) {
        [self schedule:@selector(update:)];
        _score = 0;
```

Then increment (add 1 to) your `_score` variable and set the string (the text content) of your `_scoreLabel` to that value.

```
        if (CGRectIntersectsRect(projectileRect, targetRect)) {
            [targetsToDelete addObject:target];     
            _score++;
            [_scoreLabel setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", _score]];                    
        }
```

The line `[_scoreLabel setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", _score]];` is a way to convert the integer of `_score` to a string (`NSString`). It's an old C way of doing it, the `%d` means that whatever is going to be there should be displayed as an integer as opposed to a float (having decimal points).

It also looks like you need to "instantiate" your label and add it as a child to the layer. Instantiation is just a fancy term for creating a instance of something. Think of a "class" as a blueprint for a chair, and an "instance" as a chair created from that blueprint. Once you have the chair created (an instance), you can modify it (paint it, add/remove legs, etc).

So, to instantiate your label and add it to the layer (itself):

```
-(id) init
{
    if( (self=[super init] )) {
        [self schedule:@selector(update:)];
        _score = 0;

        //Create label
        _scoreLabel = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"0" fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:16];

        //Add it to a layer (itself)
        [self addChild:_scoreLabel];
```

Comment: No problem, also, I forgot the synthesize variable. But, KK posted a great answer, and to be honest, his is more comprehensive and is better long-term solution.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `score` property in HelloWorldLayer.h after the interface declaration, like

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) int score;
```

Then synthesize it in your .m file just after the `@implementation HelloWorldLayer` line.

Create methods for setting and getting scores:

```
-(int)getScore {
    return self.score;
}

-(void)setScore:(int)newScore {
    self.score = newScore;
}
```

In the `init` method, set the value of the property to zero,

```
if( (self=[super init] )) {
//... other stuff
[self setScore:0]
}
```

You can update the score with the setScore method, but I suggest having another method for this that calls setScore so that you can use it at different places with a single line call, and make any changes like assigning more score in certain situations, like two collisions within half-a-second etc..

```
-(void)updateScore:(int)increment {
    int currentScore = [self getScore];
    [self setScore:(currentScore + increment)];
}
```

Similarly, for label,

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) CCLabelTTF scoreLabel; // in header
```

and

```
@synthesize scoreLabel; // in .m file
```

Again, in your init method, initialize the [label](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.99.5/interface_c_c_label_t_t_f.html) with position, layer and initial text etc. Then you can update that text in the updateScore method.

```
-(void)updateScore:(int)increment {
    int currentScore = [self getScore];
    [self setScore:(currentScore + increment)];

    [scoreLabel setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score: %i", [self getScore]]];
}
```

Make sure you read through the [tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH1-SW2) before going ahead in order to avoid confusion regarding common tasks.